# How to use map() inside an extension function in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I want to create an extension function that returns the total size of a list of files. This is the code:

```
fun List<Files>.totalSize(){
    return this.map {
        it.length()
    }.reduce { current, total -> current + total }
}
```

But I get `Unresolved reference: length` error message. Apparently `it` does not refer to a single file as it's supposed to but refers to the list of files instead.

I don't understand what the problem is. Any Help Please?

Comment: I think you want an extension on `List<File>`, not `List<Files>`.

Comment: Your `totalSize` function should also specify a return type (e.g. `Long`).

Comment: The `reduce(...)` call can be simplified to `sum()`.

Comment: `fun List<File>.totalSize() = sum { it.length() }`

Comment: Wait, are you trying to get the total file size? There is no `length()` method for a File. Or are you trying to get the total size of a list of lists? `fun List<List<*>>.totalSize = sum {  it.size }`

Answer (score 0):

As you guys mentioned in the comments, it was a stupid typo. And I didn't know about `sum()`. So this is my final code:

```
fun List<File>.totalSize(): Long{
    return this.map {
        it.length()
    }.sum()
}
```

Thanks guys